# Bootstrap 4 form validation with Stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, stripe-payments

Does anyone know how to make Stripe payment popup appear only when Bootstrap 4 form is valid?

✓ Bootstrap code works when form is invalid.
 Problem: I tried with 'if else' statement to make Stripe appear when the form is valid but nothing happens :(

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
          var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: 'pk_test_zef7efzhke73gefezzzhgu3',
            image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
            locale: 'auto',
            token: function(token) {
              // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
              // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
            }
          });
          // Open Checkout with further options:
          handler.open({
            name: 'Test',
            description: '2 widgets',
            currency: 'eur',
            amount: 2000
          });

          // Close Checkout on page navigation:
          window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
            handler.close();
          });



        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');


      }, false);
    });

  }, false);


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the demo code for this bootstrap component they only prevent the submission of the form if the validation fails. In your case you want to prevent it all the time otherwise the page would redirect to another one (or reload the page if you did not put an action attribute on the form) once the validation succeeds instead of opening the Checkout modal.

The easiest way is to move around the following before the if statement:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Unrelated to your issue but you probably want to move the `StripeCheckout.configure(...)` part outside of the validation logic so that you instantiate Checkout only once when the page loads.

For reference, here is the full snippet I used to make it work, but you'd still need to add some code in the `token: function(token) {...}` callback to send the token to your backend once everything is done:

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_g6do5S237ekq10r65BnxO6S0',
      image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function(token) {
          // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
          // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
      }
  });
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          // Custom behavior when Validation fails
        } else {
          // Open Checkout with further options:
          handler.open({
              name: 'Test',
              description: '2 widgets',
              currency: 'eur',
              amount: 2000
          });
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```